# How do I make a CMS out of my django app?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a django app that allows admin to post articles, and users to comment on them.

I also allowed admins to have their own dashboards and their own links to their articles.

How do I allow admins to point their existing domains to their sites?

Comment: I'm a little confused at what you're asking. You want their domains to point to your django app? This will most likely require changing their [A Record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/) on their hosting site

Comment: I want their domain to point to their space in my django app. Like: www.djangoapp.com/username

Comment: They will have to point their domains by their registrant of course but how do we allow our django app to redirect to their domains and how do we allow them to enter the domain on UI.

Comment: You'll need to use routing. Django uses [URL Dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) or [Routers in Django Rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)